# How to resize and save an image which uploaded using file upload control in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload, razor, image-resizing

i have developed a web application using asp.net mvc4 and razor. in my application there's a file upload control to upload an image and save in a temporary location.

before save image should re-sized to a specific size and then save in the temporary location given.

here is the code i have used in controller class.

```
public class FileUploadController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /FileUpload/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult FileUpload()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
    {
        if (uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string relativePath = "~/img/" + Path.GetFileName(uploadFile.FileName);
            string physicalPath = Server.MapPath(relativePath);


            FileUploadModel.ResizeAndSave(relativePath, uploadFile.FileName, uploadFile.InputStream, uploadFile.ContentLength, true);

            return View((object)relativePath);
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

and here is the code used in model class

```
public class FileUploadModel
{
    [Required]
    public HttpPostedFileWrapper ImageUploaded { get; set; }

    public static void ResizeAndSave(string savePath, string fileName, Stream imageBuffer, int maxSideSize, bool makeItSquare)
    {
        int newWidth;
        int newHeight;
        Image image = Image.FromStream(imageBuffer);
        int oldWidth = image.Width;
        int oldHeight = image.Height;
        Bitmap newImage;
        if (makeItSquare)
        {
            int smallerSide = oldWidth >= oldHeight ? oldHeight : oldWidth;
            double coeficient = maxSideSize / (double)smallerSide;
            newWidth = Convert.ToInt32(coeficient * oldWidth);
            newHeight = Convert.ToInt32(coeficient * oldHeight);
            Bitmap tempImage = new Bitmap(image, newWidth, newHeight);
            int cropX = (newWidth - maxSideSize) / 2;
            int cropY = (newHeight - maxSideSize) / 2;
            newImage = new Bitmap(maxSideSize, maxSideSize);
            Graphics tempGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);
            tempGraphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            tempGraphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            tempGraphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            tempGraphic.DrawImage(tempImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, maxSideSize, maxSideSize), cropX, cropY, maxSideSize, maxSideSize, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
        else
        {
            int maxSide = oldWidth >= oldHeight ? oldWidth : oldHeight;

            if (maxSide > maxSideSize)
            {
                double coeficient = maxSideSize / (double)maxSide;
                newWidth = Convert.ToInt32(coeficient * oldWidth);
                newHeight = Convert.ToInt32(coeficient * oldHeight);
            }
            else
            {
                newWidth = oldWidth;
                newHeight = oldHeight;
            }
            newImage = new Bitmap(image, newWidth, newHeight);
        }
        newImage.Save(savePath + fileName + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        image.Dispose();
        newImage.Dispose();
    }
}
```

but when i run the application it occurs an **ArgumentException**.

it says **"Parameter is not valid"** in following code line

```
Bitmap tempImage = new Bitmap(image, newWidth, newHeight);
```

how do i pass valid and appropriate parameters here

```
public static void ResizeAndSave(string savePath, string fileName, Stream imageBuffer, int maxSideSize, bool makeItSquare)
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Its very difficult to understand what is the problem with your code. But may be you want to use alternative way. You need to add the reference to System.Web.Helpers namespace and try the following code.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        WebImage img = new WebImage(file.InputStream);
        if (img.Width > 1000)
            img.Resize(1000, 1000);
        img.Save("path");
        return View();
    }
```

Also this class supports the crop, flip, watermark operation etc.

Comment: Hi.. thanks for uploading the post.but your code is working if the image sizes is under 1 MB..if i upload 3 MB or 2 MB image size than it give error message "Out of memory."Can u please help me...

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: Hi.. 
On local machine its working fine but whenever i deploy it its throwing webpages ka exception.

Comment: @user3217843 your Problem can be solved by increasing Runtime. Because it takes little longer for the system to Upload 2MB File in order to solve this go to your Web.Config Under <system.web> Write '<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097152" />'  What this will do is it will Increase the time of the system and your Memory Problem will be solved

Comment: Abdul Hannan Have already increased the limit in config but no use..was getting the same issue..

Comment: my issue is fixed by adding the bindingConfiguration of the service.<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IABC" receiveTimeout="00:30:00"
          sendTimeout="00:30:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>

Comment: There is no need to If statement : img.Resize(1000, 1, true, true);

Comment: I was going everywhere on the net to find this and here it is. Thank you so much!